# sending request and parameter when submit from using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to submit a form using jquery `.post()`. I want to send all the input names in addition to another parameter, in there any way to send data and the request?

```
 $.post("RegistrarManagementServlet",{"option":"cancelRequest"},function(){
                alert("hi");
            });
```

here is how we submit the request

```
  $.post("RegistrarManagementServlet",request,function(){
                alert("hi");
            });
```

I want to send all the data in the form (in the normal post request) in addition to option parameter, how can I make it?

**EDIT**

where should I define the request as function parameter, since the code occurs after confirmation dialog appear

```
$('#cancelRequest').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    jConfirm('Are you sure to delete registrar request?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(result) {

        if(result == true){
            request.cancelRequest="cancelRequest";   //request is not defiend
            $.post("RegistrarManagementServlet",request,function(){
                alert("hi");
            });
          }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make name value pair by using following code

```
 var elem = document.getElementById('frmName').elements;
 for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
   {
      //Make the pairs like 
        //{"option":"cancelRequest"}
      //elem[i].name will give you the name and
      //elem[i].value will give you the value of the field           
   }
```

then post your request just the way you do.

Or you can see the example at 
http://www.codeunit.co.za/2009/11/04/jquery-iterate-through-a-forms-elements/
for a Jquery way to do the same

Answer (score 2):

```
request.option = "cancelRequest";

$.post("RegistrarManagementServlet", request, function(){
  alert("hi");
});
```

Comment: Is there a jquery request object that one can send in the call?

Comment: Where should I define the request parameter, this code occur when confirmation dialog occurs, check the edit section

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought `request` was already defined. In that case, try this: `$.post("RegistrarManagementServlet?" + $('form').serialize() + "&option=cancelRequest", function() { });`

Comment: @Vibhu, I tried this way but all data reach NULL in the server!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `$.extend()`: `$.post('url', $.extend(request, {more: 'parameters'}), function...`